# Display image on public profile page

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, flask, phpmyadmin, flask-login

Hey I am new on flask and I am trying to make a login and registration system, also I want to display profile photo too that is been uploaded at the time of registration. I am able to store the photo but unable to display, atleast I think this.
Here is the code.

App.py

```
@app.route('/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    msg = ''
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'username' in request.form and 'password' in request.form and 'email' in request.form and 'photo' in request.form:
        username = request.form['username']
        password = request.form['password']
        email = request.form['email']
        photo = request.form['photo']
        cursor = mysql.connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
        cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE username = % s', (username, ))
        account = cursor.fetchone()
        if account:
            msg = 'Account already exists !'
        elif not re.match(r'[^@]+@[^@]+\.[^@]+', email):
            msg = 'Invalid email address !'
        elif not re.match(r'[A-Za-z0-9]+', username):
            msg = 'name must contain only characters and numbers !'
```

registration.html

```
<form action="{{ url_for('register')}}" method="post" autocomplete="off">
            <div class="msg">{{ msg }}</div>
            <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Enter Your Username" class="textbox" id="username" required></br></br>
            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter Your Password" class="textbox" id="password" required></br></br>
            <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter Your Email ID" class="textbox" id="email" required></br></br>
            <input type="file" name="photo" placeholder="File location" class="textbox" id="photo" required></br></br>
            <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Register">
            </form>
```

display.html

```
<table class="worddark"></br></br></br></br>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Username:</td>
                                    <td>{{ account['username'] }}</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Password:</td>
                                    <td>{{ account['password'] }}</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Email ID:</td>
                                    <td>{{ account['email'] }}</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Profile:</td>
                                    <td>{{ account['photo'] }}</td>
                                </tr>
```

I am trying to get the solution for displaying the image on profile

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the html `<img>` tag and place your route inside `src` attribute.

If you saved the image only by the name `example.jpeg` you need the specify the whole route in the src attribute `<img src="/your/path/example.jpeg">`.

Comment: I want to display profile image of that person. So I used `<img src="{{ account['photo'] }}">`
This is not showing me proper result.

Comment: You may have the following problems:

1. You dont specify the full route to the image like in the example listed above.

2. You dind't upload the photo correctly for example your form does not have `enctype="multipart/form-data` attribute for file upload. 

3. In order to display a image you need to save it either in a temporary location or a final folder. Then based on that location you can display it.